# Why are results prefaced with colon in ob-ipython?

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to evaluate the following code in `emacs`, using `ob-ipython`

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session :results output
lstt = ["2","3"]
for l in lstt:
  print l
#+END_SRC
```

But it returns

```
#+RESULTS:
: 2
: 3
```

Why am I seeing the colon at the beginning of the results section?

Comment: @mankoff: thanks. I'd be willing to accept your answer and upvote it, if you'd write it as a proper answer. I'm not sure, however, what you mean with "this does not replace results", but maybe you can expand on it in the answer? Also, is there any "impact" at all by using the "raw" property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:results output raw` removes the `:`. However, raw output means results from repeated execution of that code block are prepended. The results are not replaced.

Answer (score 3):

Org is protecting the results of code evaluation so they don’t get interpreted as document text.  You can see that this is expected behavior in, e.g., the [Results of Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-evaluation.html#Results-of-evaluation) section of the manual, specifically Section 14.9.2.2.

The [results header arg](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-evaluation.html#Results-of-evaluation) section of the manual runs down all the options you have for formatting the results of code block evaluation.

`:results raw` will turn off all protection, so the results will get interpreted as document text.  As another answer noted, this means that future evaluations of the source block will prepend new results before the old results (because the old results have become “just the next paragraph” from Org’s perspective).  `:results raw drawer` will turn off the protection but will also wrap the results in an Org drawer like `:RESULTS: … :END:`.  Future evaluations can then replace the whole drawer, including the old results.

Answer (score 2):

With the header argument `:results output`, executing an org source block will result in whatever is printed to standard output by the code in the block being inserted into the org buffer. If the output is only a few lines, each line begins with a `:` to give it "literal" markup. If the output is longer, it gets wrapped in a `#+begin_example ... #+end_example` block.

You can control how this happens with the variable `org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output`. By default it is set to 10, meaning output that is less than 10 lines long gets the `:` markup, and anything longer gets wrapped in a block. [See a related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39390/force-org-to-use-instead-of-begin-example-for-source-block-output)

If you don't want either of these options, you have to use the `:results output raw` option that @mankoff suggested, or check other options in the org manual node `(org) results`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `:results output verbatim code`. The `code` option wraps your results in `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC`. It might not be perfect, because your output might not be code, but it gets rid of the colons and - in case of multiple evaluation - the results are replaced :)