# Force org to use `:` instead of `begin_example` for source block output

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When executing a source block in org mode with the output set to `verbatim`, it will sometimes wrap the results in an `#begin_example` block, and sometimes it uses `:` symbols at the beginning of the line. How can I force it to do one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the variable `org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output`:

> The minimum number of lines for block output.
>   If number of lines of output is equal to or exceeds this
>   value, the output is placed in a #+begin_example...#+end_example
>   block.  Otherwise the output is marked as literal by inserting
>   colons at the starts of the lines.  This variable only takes
>   effect if the :results output option is in effect.

The default value for this variable is 10. So if you want to force babel to use `:`, you need to set this to a suitably large number, e.g.,

```
(setq org-babel-min-lines-for-block-output 1000)
```

Conversely, you can set it to 0 to force babel to always use the `begin_example` format.